# Realloc Function not Working correctly?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, sizeof, realloc

Why does the following code output 4 twice, instead of 8 and 20?
Thanks

```
int size = 0;
int *pointer;
pointer = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
size = sizeof(pointer);
printf("%d", size);
int *temp = realloc(pointer, 5 * sizeof(int));
if (temp != NULL) //realloc was successful
{
    pointer = temp;
} else //there was an error
{
    free(pointer);
    printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
}
size = sizeof(pointer);
printf("%d", size);
```

Comment: The size of the pointer hasn't changed, has it now.

Comment: @KerrekSB
didn't it change by the statement pointer=temp?
and still, by the malloc function, should it be assigned 8 bytes instead of 4?
Thanks!

Comment: You may or may not have changed the *value* of the pointer, but not the size of the pointer type.

Answer (score 9):

`sizeof` is a **compile-time** operator that tells you how much space a variable or a type takes up. The answer you get is a **constant**. In the case of a pointer, `sizeof` tells you how many bytes it takes to store a memory address. This is typically 4 bytes on a 32-bit platform and 8 bytes on a 64-bit one.

It does not tell you how much memory has been allocated by `malloc()`. As it turns out, there unfortunately is no standard function to tell you the size of an allocated memory block. You have to keep track of it yourself.

Comment: so in this case, pointer does have 8 and 20 bytes? meaning this was a misuse of the function sizeof rather than realloc not working correctly?

Comment: @user3126802 Correct.

Comment: Is there any way to check the size of the pointer?
Thank you!

Comment: @user3126802 No, there is not.

Comment: what i'm trying to do is create a list in a contiguous manner. I would like to know how many elements are in my list. I was going to use sizeof(list)/sizeof(element) but clearly, this won't work. I'm guessing a counter has to be kept whilst the user is adding the elements. How do you propose I do this please?

Comment: @user3126802: Err, that is exactly what you did. You checked the size of the **pointer**, which is probably 4 or 8 depending on your platform. What you seem to want to do is check the size of the memory allocated at the address pointed to by the pointer. The C stdlib does not offer a standard way of doing this.

Comment: @user3126802 As I said in my answer, you have to keep track of the size yourself. Like in a separate variable. C places the burden on you to remember how much memory you allocated.

Comment: `sizeof` isn't always evaluated at compile time. It depends.

Comment: @JohnKugelman so having a variable of type int in one of my structs and adding on to it should do the trick? 
Thanks all, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof` is evaluated at compile time, not run time (except in the case of variable length arrays, an odd feature of C99). In this case you're taking the size of the pointer, which is 4 bytes. Even if you took `sizeof(*pointer)`, that would be equivalent to saying `sizeof(int)`

I realize you're *trying* to tell the size of the dynamically allocated memory, but there is no standard way to do this. You should just keep track of it yourself, in your own code.

Comment: how would I be able to do this?
what i'm trying to do is create a list in a contiguous manner. I would like to know how many elements are in my list. I was going to use sizeof(list)/sizeof(element) but clearly, this won't work. I'm guessing a counter has to be kept whilst the user is adding the elements. How do you propose I do this please?

Comment: @user3126802 Use a separate variable to store to the length of the list. Or use something like `std::vector` which will allocate memory and keep track of its size on its own. That's the only general solution.